# What are the 0 bytes at the end of an Ethernet frame in Wireshark?

Tags: frame, wireshark, ethernet, mac-address

after ARP protocol in a frame, there are many 0 bytes. Does anyone know the reason for the existence of these 0 bytes?
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check the **Ethernet II** accordion, all the 0 are labelled as padding.

Ethernet requires that all packets be at least 60 bytes long (64 bytes if you include the Frame Check Sequence at the end), so if a packet is less than 60 bytes long (including the 14-byte Ethernet header), additional padding bytes have to be added to the end of the packet.

(Those padding bytes will not show up on packets sent by the machine running Wireshark; the padding is added by the Ethernet hardware, and packets being sent by the machine capturing the traffic are given to the program *before* being handed to the hardware, so they haven't been padded.)

[image: wireshark explanation]

Comment: Why do all packets need to be 60 bytes long?

Comment: From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Payload): _Note d: Minimum payload size is dictated by the 512-bit slot time used for [collision detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_detection) in the Ethernet LAN architecture._